# Kubuntu 22.04 doesn't shutdown on Lenovo Thinkpad P14

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, shutdown, thinkpad

I have a brand new Lenovo ThinkPad P14 with 13th Gen Intel Core i7-1370P and 64Gb or RAM.
Secure Boot is disabled.

Had no issues installing the system and the system has no issues booting up.

However the system can't fully shutdown/reboot. Once triggering a shutdown the normal processes completes and the laptop stays hanging on the Lenovo splash screen.

I have to turn it off by holding the power button for 20 sec.

There are no errors in the log, the output for journalctl -b-1 finishes with:

```
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-38bc426c\x2dd0a0\x2d48d4\x2d8529\x2dded397feafaf.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopped File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/38bc426c-d0a0-48d4-8529-ded397feafaf.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Removed slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopped target Preparation for Local File Systems.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Aug 29 12:08:23 william-thinkpad systemd-journald[440]: Journal stopped
```

/var/log/syslog finishes with:

```
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping Thunderbolt system service...
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping irqbalance daemon...
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping PackageKit Daemon...
Aug 29 12:08:21 william-thinkpad systemd[1]: Stopping Power Profiles daemon...
```

At this point I'm not even sure where to look and for what. Any experience or ideas very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Installing 23.04 has resolved the issue.